# ComboBox en DataGridView obteniendo el valor en el evento SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Windows Forms en el cual tengo varios ComboBox en diferentes columnas de un DataGridView.

La necesidad que tengo es tomar los valores en el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` de cada control ComboBox, tengo implementado el siguiente código.

```
private void dgvDetCatalogo_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        if (dText != null)
        {
            dText.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(dText_KeyDown);
            dText.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dText_KeyDown);
        }

        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl dgvCombo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(dgvCombo_SelectedIndexChanged);
            dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dgvCombo_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }

    private void dgvCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            if (dgvDetCatalogo.Columns[_index].Name == "colMedida")
            {
                _cboUnidadMedida = Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedValue);
                MessageBox.Show($"_cboUnidadMedida: {_cboUnidadMedida}");
            }

            if (dgvDetCatalogo.Columns[_index].Name == "colImpuesto")
            {
                _cboImpuesto = Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedValue);
                MessageBox.Show($"_cbolImpuesto: {_cboImpuesto}");
            }
        } 
    }
```

El index para ponerselo al Row lo tomo de este evento.

```
private void dgvDetCatalogo_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvDetCatalogo.CurrentRow == null)
            return;

        _index = dgvDetCatalogo.CurrentRow.Index;
    }
```

La variable _index la tengo declarada a nivel de formulario para poder ponerla en el `row` del evento `SelectedIndexChanged`

> El problema que he notado cuando selecciono otro elemento del ComboBox
>   es que no lo toma si al momento de cambiar de elemento no presiono la
>   tecla ENTER ó TAB

[image: DataGridView SelectedIndexChanged]

Al no saber controlar eso, creo que la solución es tomar los valores de los combox en el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` si hay otra manera de que cuando se seleccione algún elemento de los combos se confirme el cambio de elemento.

El problema que tengo ahora es que cuando selecciono otro combo de la misma columna o otro combo de otra columna me da el siguiente error, borra todo lo que había en esa celda hasta desaparece el combo.

[image: Error combo]

La intención de lo que esta implementado en el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` es que trato de obtener el id de lo que selecciono en cada ComboBox para luego utilizarlo en otro lugar. El problema es que no entra en ninguna condición `If` donde tengo el nombre de cada columna que es de tipo ComboBox, ¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estuve intentando solucionarlo y logre hacerlo con el evento `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`

> `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` Tiene lugar cuando el estado de una
>   celda cambia con relación a un cambio en su contenido.

A partir de ahí implemente el siguiente código.

```
private void dgvDetCatalogo_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvDetCatalogo.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            dgvDetCatalogo.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
```

Y ya no es necesario la implementación del evento `SelectedIndexChanged`

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estas utilizando el índice de la fila `rowIndex` cuando lo que realmente necesitas es el índice de la columna `ColumnIndex` . Por otra parte, hay que decir, que te puedes ahorrar el evento `CellClick` ya que desde el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` puedes acceder al `ColumnIndex`. Te dejo el código

```
private void dgvCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (dgvDetCatalogo.CurrentRow == null)
            return;
        var _index = dgvDetCatalogo.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            if (dgvDetCatalogo.Columns[_index].Name == "colMedida")
            {
                _cboUnidadMedida = Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedValue);
                MessageBox.Show($"_cboUnidadMedida: {_cboUnidadMedida}");
            }

            if (dgvDetCatalogo.Columns[_index].Name == "colImpuesto")
            {
                _cboImpuesto = Convert.ToInt32(combo.SelectedValue);
                MessageBox.Show($"_cbolImpuesto: {_cboImpuesto}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero que te ayude, cualquier otro problema comentamelo e intento ayudarte.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola hice los cambios que me solicitaste y si funciona pero me da el siguiente error el cual comento en mi pregunta original haciendo una actualización.